# How is possible to export ant Project generated programmatically into build.xml

Tags: ant, export, project, build.xml

I am using ant externally, i.e. I construct org.apache.tools.ant.Project dynamically 
in my program: setup its Tasks, Targets etc., then I want to create build.xml file. How is possible? How possible export this project into ordinal ant build.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with the ant codebase a lot recently, and I'm afraid I don't think this is possible.

Since you're the one generating the project in the first place, it might be easier if you generate the XML at the same time.

Comment: thanks, I did not find this possibility and do not sure should I dig into - to search is it possible or not. Anyway the question is open...
Strange what ant developers do not think to implement this nice feature.

Comment: It's open source. You could always go and implement it yourself and contribute it back to the community.